# SpriteKit Fixed Joints

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a SKSpriteNode called "SpikyRedBall" which is a red ball. I wanted to add spikes to it so I used the following code. I can see the Spike attached to the ball but when the ball collides with another ball it does not take the fixed joints into consideration and moves them separately. I am using the following implementation:

```
@implementation SpikyRedBall

-(instancetype) init
{
    self = [super init];
    [self attachSpikes];
    return self;
}

    -(void) attachSpikes
    {
        Spike *spike = [[Spike alloc] init];
        spike.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);

        // attach the joint
        SKPhysicsJointFixed *ballAndSpikeJointFixed = [SKPhysicsJointFixed jointWithBodyA:self.physicsBody bodyB:spike.physicsBody anchor:CGPointZero];

        [self.scene.physicsWorld addJoint:ballAndSpikeJointFixed];
        [self addChild:spike];
    }

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you don't have collision or contact categories setup for the spikes themselves.  I would try setting all physicsBody properties on the spikes to be identical to those of the balls, but obviously ensuring that they don't have collision or contact categories setup in a way that they would collide with their own parent ball.

Answer (score 2):

If you can require iOS 7.1, you could use `+bodyWithBodies:` instead of attaching any joints.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you  just add the spikes to the sprite image? If they need to disappear or fall off you can just create multiple versions of the image without spikes.

Comment: But the Physicsbody would then need a complex shape.